A read barrier function on linux
I could not find a solution to my problem.
I am interested in multi processor programming, and specificly I am trying to deal with issue of writes on other cores being not-visible on my local core.
I am specifically working on x86, so if no such linux function exists, a machine insturction (if there is one), will also do the trick.
I found this wikipedia page - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol#Invalidate_Queues
which seems to discuss this issue. According to this page, a read barrier can be used to make sure writes to the internal write buffers on other cores are visable on my core. My problem is I could not find any such function.
Any help will be appericiated.

The "the internal write buffers" (e.g. the store buffer, and perhaps the LFBs if used for write coalescing before a read-for-ownership completes) aren't visible at all to other cores.  It simply takes time for them to commit to other cores.  All you can do is make sure that memory operations from your writer threads become globally visible in the right order, e.g. with mfence or a dummy lock add byte [rsp], 0 or something if you need earlier stores to be visible before later loads.

On the read side, x86 does acquire (https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/) for free, so if you've seen a value from one store, your loads will also see all earlier stores (from that thread, or on x86 all earlier stores globally since there is a total store order.)  There is no way to ask loads to wait for any data that might currently be in the store buffer of other cores.  They effectively haven't happened yet as far as other cores are concerned.

I've never seen an example of an algorithm that needed a memory barrier because of invalidation queues, when the same problematic reordering couldn't have also happened for other reasons (like out-of-order exec of loads).  So I don't get why it's interesting to talk about them.  I suspect there might be something obscure and haven't really spent much effort looking for an example, but store buffers have much bigger and more obvious effects.

You have tagged [c].  The C-language solution to essentially all such problems is to ensure that your program is free of data races (in the C sense), which is achieved largely by use of appropriate synchronization objects and / or atomic operations with appropriate memory-ordering semantics.  There is nothing about that specific to x86.  If you're writing (inline) assembly then that's a different story, but you should not engage assembly for this purpose alone.

@PeterCordes
Thank you for the response. I guess marking [c] was a mistake. I am mostly interested in C, and specifically in x86. But I would like my program to be as portable as possible.
I have reduced my problem to asserting that on context-switch (say in linux), the store buffer of the local cache is flushed. Is that correct? I could not find a documentation stating as such.
I see from the linux kernel code on context_switch function there is this call:
#define barrier() __asm__ __volatile__("": : :"memory")
Is it a store barrier which flush the store buffer?

@JohnBollinger
tagged you as well

@NivSulimany: No, that barrier doesn't involve any asm instructions, it only blocks compile-time reordering. (https://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/). On x86, that makes it sufficient for atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acq_rel) but not seq_cst because x86 allows StoreLoad reordering (https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/).  On most other ISAs, it's only atomic_signal_fence(seq_cst), only useful for ordering against code that will run on the same core like signal handlers.

If you're writing Linux kernel code, you should read the appropriate memory-model doc.  (https://www9.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0124r6.html).
Otherwise you should read about the ISO C stdatomic.h functions like atomic_store_explicit( pointer, value, memory_order ).  And Jeff Preshing's articles, some of which I linked in my previous comment, for an understanding of what concepts and functionality these APIs are trying to present.

@NivSulimany, if portability is indeed your objective then handling the issue with the C language's standard tools is far preferable to doing anything in any assembly language.  Portability is one of the primary (potential) advantages of writing in a high-level language.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
